# How to put illimited or more than 32767 to the value of lineze for sqlplus

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, max, sqlplus

I have a problem, i have a csv export which i have more than 1000000 charactere, the export is done from sqlplus and when i have more than 32767 the spool return to the line whicch is normal because i have  set linesize 32767

```
set head off
set feed off
set echo off
set termout off
set serveroutput on
set pages 0
set long 1000000000
set linesize 32767
set trimspool on
set tab off
set longchunksize 32767
```

when i try to do put more than 32767 i get this exception

```
SP2-0267: linesize option 100000 out of range (1 through 32767)
```

can I have some help or should I search for another solution;

Thanks

Comment: You mean, one line in your CSV is over 1000000 characters long?

Comment: no i have a lot of lines but when i'm at the 32767 i return the line even if my line isn't at the end